# iOS Getter and Setter confusion

Tags: ios, ios4

I think that I am a bit confused about iOS @property getter and setters. I am trying to set an NSString iVar in my AppDelegate.h file from another class so that it can be used by all of the classes in the project?

For example, I am working on an iPhone project that stores an iVar NSString *currentUser in AppDelegate.h. I need to be able to set this through one method in a ViewController.m and then get it through another method in a second ViewController?

Maybe Getter and Setter is the wrong direction of attack all together? I understand that i don't want to alloc init the AppDelegate as the iVar will only exist in that object and I want it accessible to ALL objects in ALL classes?

Please someone set me straight.

All the best,
Darren

Comment: It seems like using a singleton may be a solution; have you tried that? (Although I know a few people who aren't fond of using singletons as a solution)

Comment: The app delegate is effectively acting as a singleton. There is usually only ever one instance at play, and it is accessible from anywhere via the UIApplication singleton. Can't swing a dead cat in iOS without hitting a singleton...

Comment: I looked at singleton's and thought that there might be a simpler way. I like Bill's solution using the app delegate. Now just got to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setup for the app delegate.

```
@interface AppDelegate
{
   NSString *__currentUser;
}
@property (monatomic, copy) NSString* currentUser;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize currentUser = __currentUser;

- (void) dealloc
{
   [__currentUser release];
   [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

From one view controller, you could set a value for the current user, and from a subsequent view controller, get that value for some nefarious purpose.

```
@implementation LoginController
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    AppDelegate *bob = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [bob setCurrentUser: @"Jim Kirk"];
    ...
}
@end
```

In some other view controller that appears later, the value of the current user can be accessed.

```
@implementation ProfileViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   ...
   AppDelegate *bob = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSString * user = [bob currentUser];

   // insert nefarious purpose for current user value here
   ...
}
@end
```

Comment: Hey thanks Bill this has Just about got me there. Really handy knowledge there. I have now got my code to set the variable no problems but I am wondering if you could elaborate a little more on accessing the Var as your code there doesn't seem to be correct?

Comment: I updated my answer to do a cast to AppDelegate*. You may not need the cast, actually, since the value is being assigned to a local variable of type AppDelegate. It won't hurt anything to have it in there. A common solution to the long UIApplication incantation is to create a macro for it in your prefix header file. #define APP_DELEGATE = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate], then use APP_DELEGATE whenever needed. Eg [APP_DELEGATE currentUser];

Comment: Thanks to Bill's code I got the last part working now. Replaced
NSString * user = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] currentUser];
With this:

AppDelegate *user = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *currentUser = user.currentUser;
// just to prove it works
NSLog(@"This is the currentUser: %@",currentUser);
Thanks guys this answers my question. I was not really looking at Getters and setters in the correct way.